# blender上のpythonで、webカメラの画像が読み込めない

Tags: python, opencv, blender

環境
Blender2.8
Python 3.7.3
macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

上記の環境の元、https://youtu.be/O7nNO3FLkLU　こちらのリンク先の動画にあるように、blenderのpythonからopencvを使ってwebカメラを読み込みたいです。

しかし以下のようなエラーが出て、カメラを読み込むことができません。

[ERROR:0] VIDEOIO(AVFOUNDATION): raised unknown C++ exception! Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/okadanaoki/Desktop/mocapdata/Vincent.blend/Text.001", line 83, in modal cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor' location: :-1 location: :-1

以下に全文を載せておきます。

```
import bpy
from imutils import face_utils
import dlib
import cv2
import time
import numpy
from bpy.props import FloatProperty

class OpenCVAnimOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.opencv_operator"
    bl_label = "OpenCV Animation Operator"

    # p = our pre-treined model directory
    p = "/Users/okadanaoki/Desktop/mocapdata/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat" # macOS
    #p = "/home/jason/Downloads/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat" # linux
    detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(p)

    _timer = None
    _cap  = None

    width = 800
    height = 600

    stop :bpy.props.BoolProperty()

    # 3D model points.    
    model_points = numpy.array([
                                (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),             # Nose tip
                                (0.0, -330.0, -65.0),        # Chin
                                (-225.0, 170.0, -135.0),     # Left eye left corner
                                (225.0, 170.0, -135.0),      # Right eye right corne
                                (-150.0, -150.0, -125.0),    # Left Mouth corner
                                (150.0, -150.0, -125.0)      # Right mouth corner
                            ], dtype = numpy.float32)
    # Camera internals
    camera_matrix = numpy.array(
                            [[height, 0.0, width/2],
                            [0.0, height, height/2],
                            [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]], dtype = numpy.float32
                            )

    # Keeps a moving average of given length
    def smooth_value(self, name, length, value):
        if not hasattr(self, 'smooth'):
            self.smooth = {}
        if not name in self.smooth:
            self.smooth[name] = numpy.array([value])
        else:
            self.smooth[name] = numpy.insert(arr=self.smooth[name], obj=0, values=value)
            if self.smooth[name].size > length:
                self.smooth[name] = numpy.delete(self.smooth[name], self.smooth[name].size-1, 0)
        sum = 0
        for val in self.smooth[name]:
            sum += val
        return sum / self.smooth[name].size


    # Keeps min and max values, then returns the value in a ranve 0 - 1
    def get_range(self, name, value):
        if not hasattr(self, 'range'):
            self.range = {}
        if not name in self.range:
            self.range[name] = numpy.array([value, value])
        else:
            self.range[name] = numpy.array([min(value, self.range[name][0]), max(value, self.range[name][1])] )
        val_range = self.range[name][1] - self.range[name][0]
        if val_range != 0:
            return (value - self.range[name][0]) / val_range
        else:
            return 0

    def modal(self, context, event):

        if (event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}) or self.stop == True:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            self.init_camera()
            _, image = self._cap.read()
            if image is None:
                #cv2.imwrite("/Users/okadanaoki/Desktop/test.png", image)
                print("None")
                image = cv2.imread("/Users/okadanaoki/Desktop/800x600.jpg")

            print("image4");
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            rects = self.detector(gray, 0)
            # bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)

            # For each detected face, find the landmark.
            for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
                shape = self.predictor(gray, rect)
                shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

                #2D image points. If you change the image, you need to change vector
                image_points = numpy.array([shape[30],     # Nose tip - 31
                                            shape[8],      # Chin - 9
                                            shape[36],     # Left eye left corner - 37
                                            shape[45],     # Right eye right corne - 46
                                            shape[48],     # Left Mouth corner - 49
                                            shape[54]      # Right mouth corner - 55
                                        ], dtype = numpy.float32)

                dist_coeffs = numpy.zeros((4,1)) # Assuming no lens distortion

                if hasattr(self, 'rotation_vector'):
                    (success, self.rotation_vector, self.translation_vector) = cv2.solvePnP(self.model_points, 
                        image_points, self.camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, flags=cv2.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE, 
                        rvec=self.rotation_vector, tvec=self.translation_vector, 
                        useExtrinsicGuess=True)
                else:
                    (success, self.rotation_vector, self.translation_vector) = cv2.solvePnP(self.model_points, 
                        image_points, self.camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, flags=cv2.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE, 
                        useExtrinsicGuess=False)

                if not hasattr(self, 'first_angle'):
                    self.first_angle = numpy.copy(self.rotation_vector)

                bones = bpy.data.objects["vincent_blenrig"].pose.bones

                bones["head_fk"].rotation_euler[0] = self.smooth_value("h_x", 3, (self.rotation_vector[0] - self.first_angle[0])) / 1   # Up/Down
                bones["head_fk"].rotation_euler[2] = self.smooth_value("h_y", 3, -(self.rotation_vector[1] - self.first_angle[1])) / 1.5  # Rotate
                bones["head_fk"].rotation_euler[1] = self.smooth_value("h_z", 3, (self.rotation_vector[2] - self.first_angle[2])) / 1.3   # Left/Right

                bones["mouth_ctrl"].location[2] = self.smooth_value("m_h", 2, -self.get_range("mouth_height", numpy.linalg.norm(shape[62] - shape[66])) * 0.06 )
                bones["mouth_ctrl"].location[0] = self.smooth_value("m_w", 2, (self.get_range("mouth_width", numpy.linalg.norm(shape[54] - shape[48])) - 0.5) * -0.04)
                bones["brow_ctrl_L"].location[2] = self.smooth_value("b_l", 3, (self.get_range("brow_left", numpy.linalg.norm(shape[19] - shape[27])) -0.5) * 0.04)
                bones["brow_ctrl_R"].location[2] = self.smooth_value("b_r", 3, (self.get_range("brow_right", numpy.linalg.norm(shape[24] - shape[27])) -0.5) * 0.04)

                bones["head_fk"].keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", index=-1)
                bones["mouth_ctrl"].keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=-1)
                bones["brow_ctrl_L"].keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=2)
                bones["brow_ctrl_R"].keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=2)

                for (x, y) in shape:
                    cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 255), -1)

            cv2.imshow("Output", image)
            cv2.waitKey(1)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def init_camera(self):
        if self._cap == None:
            self._cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            self._cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, self.width)
            self._cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, self.height)
            self._cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def stop_playback(self, scene):
        print(format(scene.frame_current) + " / " + format(scene.frame_end))
        if scene.frame_current == scene.frame_end:
            bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(self.stop_playback)

        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.02, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        self._cap.release()
        self._cap = None

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OpenCVAnimOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OpenCVAnimOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.wm.opencv_operator()
```

よろしくおねがします。

※追記10/31
元のコードの80~85行目を記載しておきます。

```py
if event.type == 'TIMER':
            self.init_camera()
            _, image = self._cap.read()
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            rects = self.detector(gray, 0)
            # bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/220387

Comment: 83行目に`size`の呼び出しがありませんが、載せているコードは`OpenCVAnimOperator.py`と同一のものですか？

Comment: @kohei TAMURA　
コードは少し変えていて、以下のものが元のコードです。 (元のコードの80~85行目を変更しています)

```python

if event.type == 'TIMER':
            self.init_camera()
            _, image = self._cap.read()
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            rects = self.detector(gray, 0)
            # bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)
```

Comment: 83行目にsizeの呼び出しがありませんね。本当にそのエラーが出力されたんですか？エラーの内容を省略したりしていませんか？

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA 　
[ERROR:0] VIDEOIO(AVFOUNDATION): raised unknown C++ exception!


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/okadanaoki/Desktop/mocapdata/Vincent.blend/Text.001", line 83, in modal
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'


location: <unknown location>:-1

location: <unknown location>:-1

こちらのエラーがログとして出ました。申し訳ないです。。

Comment: 最初の質問のエラーと全然違いますね... :_(